# Getting a single value from np.where() to populate new column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to get the value of an np.where() function to populate an entire column, but am running into some issues. I have two tables, a lookup table that contains two columns, "injuryType", and "Id" where injuryType is a string and Id is an int. The second table is a new table that I am trying to grab the Id from the first table, but it should be the same for entire column.

```
    #LookupTable 
    Id  InjuryType
    1   acute_Shoulder
    2   chronic_Shoulder
    3   acute_Ankle
    4   chronic_Ankle


   #The table that I want to create (new)
   Id   Description
   4    a
   4    b
   4    foo
   4    bar
```

I'm struggling with the Id column of the new df. I've tried to extract the contents of the np.where() function to populate the id column to no avail.

```
 #Try setting id to Id from LookupTable where InjuryType is chronic_Ankle, essentially new['Id'] = 4
 new['Id'] = np.where(lookup['InjuryType'] == 'chronic_Ankle',lookup['Id'],'NULL')
 
 #Also tired setting the the function to a value.
 i = np.where(lookup['InjuryType'] == 'chronic_Ankle',lookup['Id'],'NULL')
 i = [i for i in i != 'NULL']  #returns ['4'], but will get index error if I try setting it to this
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of possible solutions:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Id': lookup[lookup.InjuryType == 'chronic_Ankle'].Id.item(),
    'Description': ['a', 'b', 'foo', 'bar']})
```

The result is:

```
   Id Description
0   4           a
1   4           b
2   4         foo
3   4         bar
```

Another option:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Id': lookup.set_index('InjuryType').loc['chronic_Ankle', 'Id'],
    'Description': ['a', 'b', 'foo', 'bar']})
```